# closedXML Conditional Formatting of a named range

Tags: named, named-ranges, closedxml

Need to apply conditional formatting to a named range or other range in which the cells or columns in the range are not contiguous.

'Below a named range is built from each column in which the value includes the word "DoDAAC" 
            'These columns are not necessarily beside one another and I need to know if there are duplicate values in them.
            'I am attempting to do that by creating a conditional format rule that will highlight dups throughout the columns that are not beside one another.
            'Now I know I can do this several way at creation of the sheet by collecting the values in a list, looking for dups and highlighting them.
            'But the resulting spreadsheet is distributed and updated by users after creation and if they enter a duplicate I want the cell to turn red.

'If the below range "rg" is a contiguous range, no problem the conditional formatting works. However, if there are many ranges in "rg" like "I:I,K:K,M:M" which can be the case in a named range then only the first range has the formatting applied.

rg.AddConditionalFormat().WhenIsDuplicate().Fill.SetBackgroundColor(cxl.XLColor.BabyPink).Font.SetFontColor(cxl.XLColor.Red)

```
        'Creates a named range with all the DoDAAC columns
        For Each C As cxl.IXLCell In .Row(1).CellsUsed
            If C.Value.ToString Like "*DoDAAC*" Or _
               C.Value.ToString Like "*DoDAAC*" Or _
               C.Value.ToString Like "*DoDAAC*" Then
                C.WorksheetColumn.AddToNamed("DoDAACs", ClosedXML.Excel.XLScope.Workbook
                                             )
            End If
        Next
```

'Here I attempt to apply the formatting to the named range and it only get applied to the first range in the ranges of the named range.

```
      Dim nr = wkb.Range("DoDAACs").AddConditionalFormat().WhenIsDuplicate().Fill.SetBackgroundColor(cxl.XLColor.BabyPink).Font.SetFontColor(cxl.XLColor.Red)
```

It wont work to cycle thru all the ranges and apply the formatting separately as I'm checking for duplicate across all the columns.